# Swipeable Tabs With Active Tab

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

How're you doing guys.
Please I need your help on this matter.
I've found this code on codepen : https://codepen.io/grahn195/pen/oNZvwRL and it works very perfectly on codepen.io

I wanted to create three swipeable tabs, and I've succeeded to create them perfectly. But what I want is to make the middle tab to be active instead of the first tab.

```html
  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  

  <title>CodePen - Swipeable Tabs</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.1.2/css/swiper.min.css'>
  
<style>
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0;
}

.active-mark {
  background: #ffeb3b;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 52px;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-out;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background-color: #00D42B;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #0e8927;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 56px;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition: font-weight 0.22s ease;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet:nth-of-type(1).swiper-pagination-bullet-active ~ .active-mark {
  left: 0%;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet:nth-of-type(2).swiper-pagination-bullet-active ~ .active-mark {
  left: 33.33%;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet:nth-of-type(2).swiper-pagination-bullet-active ~ .active-mark {
  left: 66.66%;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet:first-of-type.swiper-pagination-bullet-active ~ .active-mark {
  left: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

  <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>

  
  
  <script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>


</head>

<body translate="no" >
  <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-pagination">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Tab 1x</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Tab 2x</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Tab 3x</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-1b93190375e9ccc259df3a57c1abc0e64599724ae30d7ea4c6877eb615f89387.js"></script>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.1.2/js/swiper.min.js'></script>
      <script id="rendered-js" >
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  slidesPerView: 1,
  paginationClickable: true,
  loop: false,
  paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {
    var tabsName = ['Apps', 'Tricks', 'People'];
    if (index === tabsName.length - 1) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' +
      tabsName[index] + '</span>' +
      '<div class="active-mark "></div>';
    }
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + tabsName[index] + '</span>';
  } });
//# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>

  

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-initialSlide
initialSlide
Index number of initial slide.
Add the parameter
initialSlide: 1,

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32714674)